# ClassLoader referenced unknown path

Tags: java, android, warnings, classloader, android-broadcastreceiver

I am developing a personal medicine time reminder application.It is working almost properly except the fact that it is stopping after notifying the medicine time a few times.
While monitoring the log cat of the application i found that it is stopping the alarm receiver after getting the following Warning.

```
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.sakkar.medicineschedular-2/lib/arm
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been few weeks now and not sure if you have figured it out or not.

I ran into an issue where my app wouldn't connect to the localhost web service from my device. It worked fine on the emulator.
My console was showing the same warning message as your's.

Here are my troubleshooting steps to fix it:

1. Uninstalled the app from my phone
2. Deleted the directories created by
   this app earlier, on my phone
3. Disabled instant-run
4. Restarted my phone

Having failed to fix it even after these steps, I looked at my phone connections and found that the wi-fi was disabled. Enabled the wi-fi and enabled instant-run and the happy days are back.

Lesson learnt is that the warning message you are seeing is irrelevant in my case.

Hope this helps.