# ClassLoader referenced unknown path /data/app/.../1/lib/arm64

Tags: android, logcat

I am concerned what the System warning in my android app means.

> ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz-1/lib/arm64

This warning comes up when I run the app and then don't do anything - just displaying the main Activity. The app does not crash, but I'd like to know why these warnings are showing up.

This is the complete logcat when I run the application on my Sony Xperia device, but the Emulator creates similar logs.

```
11-25 17:02:48.261 27908-27908/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz I/art: Late-
enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-25 17:02:48.295 27908-27908/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz-1/lib/arm64
11-25 17:02:48.319 27908-27908/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
11-25 17:02:48.400 27908-27936/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : ce5aeb9, I750f7f2fa6
                                                                       Build Date                       : 03/24/17
                                                                       OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.09.00.03
                                                                       Local Branch                     : 
                                                                       Remote Branch                    : quic/LA.BF64.1.2.3_rb1.11
                                                                       Remote Branch                    : NONE
                                                                       Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
11-25 17:02:48.405 27908-27936/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-25 17:02:48.406 27908-27936/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
11-25 17:02:48.435 27908-27908/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@d84f7af time:215890379
```

Log on Emulator (Nexus 5 API 23 (Android 6.0, API23))

```
11-25 16:18:02.052 16216-16216/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
11-25 16:18:02.092 16216-16216/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz-1/lib/x86
11-25 16:18:02.105 16216-16216/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
11-25 16:18:02.141 16216-16241/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                                               [ 11-25 16:18:02.153 16216:16216 D/         ]
                                                                               HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xab1a4140, tid 16216
11-25 16:18:02.227 16216-16241/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-25 16:18:02.227 16216-16241/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
11-25 16:18:02.285 16216-16241/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xaee144e0: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
11-25 16:18:02.298 16216-16241/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaee144e0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xaee126f0)
11-25 16:18:02.299 16216-16241/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
11-25 16:18:02.299 16216-16241/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
11-25 16:18:02.299 16216-16241/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
11-25 16:18:02.370 16216-16241/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaee144e0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xaee126f0)
```

Log on Emulator Nexus 5X API 26 x86 (Android 8.0.0, API 26)

```
11-25 16:19:22.549 6786-6786/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
11-25 16:19:22.560 6786-6786/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
11-25 16:19:22.730 6786-6804/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
11-25 16:19:22.773 6786-6804/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-25 16:19:22.773 6786-6804/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
11-25 16:19:22.773 6786-6804/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
11-25 16:19:22.773 6786-6804/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
11-25 16:19:22.783 6786-6804/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x989fda40: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
11-25 16:19:22.811 6786-6804/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x989fda40: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xa4a8b850)
11-25 16:19:22.812 6786-6804/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
11-25 16:19:22.812 6786-6804/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
11-25 16:19:22.812 6786-6804/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
11-25 16:19:22.812 6786-6804/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
11-25 16:19:22.812 6786-6804/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
11-25 16:19:22.812 6786-6804/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
11-25 16:19:22.884 6786-6804/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x989fda40: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xa4a8b850)
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45407126/2550406) mentioned disabling instantRun, which I have already done because of my version of IntelliJ not supporting the latest version of gradle yet (last time I checked with support). It also mentions WiFi, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39654701/2550406) mentions clearing app cache and data, but this also does not make a difference.

It might be worth mentioning that the first time I run the app, IntelliJ shows the following error in the logcat. This happens both on the emulator and my real device. With "the first time", I mean that it does not show the error when I click run again and select "restart app". This behaviour is not 100% consistent though.

```
11-25 16:14:41.358 14185-14185/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
11-25 16:14:41.371 14185-14189/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
11-25 16:14:41.371 14185-14189/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
11-25 16:14:41.403 14185-14185/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/ch.ethz.inf.vs.a4.minker.einz-2/lib/x86
```

What could be reasons for these warnings? I am afraid that if I ignore them, I will at some point spend days debugging only to find out that these warnings would have told me.

Answer (score -1):

you need to set the flag of intent.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(context,Route.class);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I was not using an intent at that point... this happened while starting the main activity